# How to get into game development?

Tags: unity, game-design

I really want to get into game development and one day be able to make simple games that are enjoyable to play. I have very little experience in coding/designing. I would appretiate any help :)
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. :) This site is mainly geared toward technical questions with a concise correct answer (like "how do I solve this specific problem?"). For general ideas about how to get started, it's better to check out tutorial sites or discussion forums like gamedev.net, or to start up a conversation with people who already work in games.

Comment: Well this is not the appropriate site to ask this question. But surely i can give some directions. To suffice your needs i think you can start off with Unity. It is fairly simple to learn and easy to switch platforms. Its widely used for mobile games. Follow this link-http://unity3d.com/learn